# Optimal way of creating a cache in the PySpark environment

Tags: caching, apache-spark, pyspark, cloudant

I am using Spark Streaming for creating a system to enrich incoming data from a cloudant database. Example -

```
Incoming Message: {"id" : 123}
Outgoing Message: {"id" : 123, "data": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

My code for the driver class is as follows:

```py
from Sample.Job import EnrichmentJob
from Sample.Job import FunctionJob
import pyspark
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, SQLContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

from kafka import KafkaConsumer, KafkaProducer
import json

class SampleFramework():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def messageHandler(m):
        return json.loads(m.message)

    @staticmethod
    def processData(rdd):

        if (rdd.isEmpty()):
            print("RDD is Empty")
            return

        # Expand
        expanded_rdd = rdd.mapPartitions(EnrichmentJob.enrich)

        # Score
        scored_rdd = expanded_rdd.map(FunctionJob.function)

        # Publish RDD


    def run(self, ssc):

        self.ssc = ssc

        directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(self.ssc, QUEUENAME, \
                                                          {"metadata.broker.list": META, 
                                                          "bootstrap.servers": SERVER}, \
                                                          messageHandler= SampleFramework.messageHandler)

        directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(SampleFramework.processData)

        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Code for the the Enrichment Job is as follows:
class EnrichmentJob:

```py
cache = {}

@staticmethod
def enrich(data):

    # Assume that Cloudant Connector using the available config
    cloudantConnector = CloudantConnector(config, config["cloudant"]["host"]["req_db_name"])
    final_data = []
    for row in data:
        id = row["id"]
        if(id not in EnrichmentJob.cache.keys()):
            data = cloudantConnector.getOne({"id": id})
            row["data"] = data
            EnrichmentJob.cache[id]=data
        else:
            data = EnrichmentJob.cache[id]
            row["data"] = data
        final_data.append(row)

    cloudantConnector.close()

    return final_data
```

My question is - Is there someway to maintain [1]"a global cache on the main memory that is accessible to all workers" or [2]"local caches on each of the workers such that they remain persisted in the foreachRDD setting"?

I have already explored the following -

1. Broadcast Variables - Here we go the [1] way. As I understand, they are meant to be read-only and immutable. I have checked out this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39729059/spark-streaming-and-mutable-broadcast-variable?rq=1) but it cites an example of unpersisting/persisting the broadcasted variable. Is this a good practice?
2. Static Variables - Here we go the [2] way. The class that is being referred to ("Enricher" in this case) maintains a cache in the form of a static variable dictionary. But it turns out that the ForEachRDD function spawns a completely new process for each incoming RDD and this removes the previously initiated static variable. This is the one coded above.

I have two possible solutions right now -

1. Maintain an offline cache on the file system.
2. Do the entire computation of this enrichment task on my driver node. This would cause the entire data to end up on driver and be maintained there. The cache object will be sent to the enrichment job as an argument to the mapping function.

Here obviously the first one looks better than the second, but I wish to conclude that these two are the only ways around, before committing to them. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there someway to maintain [1]"a global cache on the main memory that is accessible to all workers"

No. There is no "main memory" which can be accessed by all workers. Each worker runs in a separate process and communicates with external world with sockets. Not to mention separation between different physical nodes in non-local mode.

There are some techniques that can be applied to achieve worker scoped cache with memory mapped data (using SQLite being the simplest one) but it takes some additional effort to implement the right way (avoid conflicts and such).

> or [2]"local caches on each of the workers such that they remain persisted in the foreachRDD setting"?

You can use standard caching techniques with scope limited to the individual worker processes. Depending on the configuration (static vs. [dynamic resource allocation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#dynamic-resource-allocation), `spark.python.worker.reuse`) it may or may not be preserved between multiple tasks and batches.

Consider following, simplified, example:

- `map_param.py`:

  ```py
  from pyspark import AccumulatorParam
  from collections import Counter

  class CounterParam(AccumulatorParam):
      def zero(self, v: Counter) -> Counter:
          return Counter()

      def addInPlace(self, acc1: Counter, acc2: Counter) -> Counter:
          acc1.update(acc2)
          return acc1
  ```
- `my_utils.py`:

  ```py
  from pyspark import Accumulator
  from typing import Hashable
  from collections import Counter

  # Dummy cache. In production I would use functools.lru_cache 
  # but it is a bit more painful to show with accumulator
  cached = {} 

  def f_cached(x: Hashable, counter: Accumulator) -> Hashable:
      if cached.get(x) is None:
          cached[x] = True
          counter.add(Counter([x]))
      return x


  def f_uncached(x: Hashable, counter: Accumulator) -> Hashable:
      counter.add(Counter([x]))
      return x
  ```
- `main.py`:

  ```py
  from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
  from pyspark import SparkContext

  from counter_param import CounterParam
  import my_utils

  from collections import Counter

  def main():
      sc = SparkContext("local[1]")
      ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 5)

      cnt_cached = sc.accumulator(Counter(), CounterParam())
      cnt_uncached = sc.accumulator(Counter(), CounterParam())

      stream = ssc.queueStream([
          # Use single partition to show cache in work
          sc.parallelize(data, 1) for data in
          [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 5]]
      ])

      stream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreach(
          lambda x: my_utils.f_cached(x, cnt_cached)))
      stream.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreach(
          lambda x: my_utils.f_uncached(x, cnt_uncached)))

      ssc.start()
      ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(15)
      ssc.stop(stopGraceFully=True)

      print("Counter cached {0}".format(cnt_cached.value))
      print("Counter uncached {0}".format(cnt_uncached.value))

  if __name__ == "__main__":
      main()
  ```

Example run:

```sh
bin/spark-submit main.py
```

```
Counter cached Counter({1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 5: 1})
Counter uncached Counter({1: 3, 2: 2, 3: 2, 5: 2})
```

As you can see we get expected results:

- For "cached" objects accumulator is updated only once per unique key per worker process (partition).
- For not-cached objects accumulator is update each time key occurs.